# Filter a dataGridComboBox column from a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

First I choose a supplier in a ComboBox Column and then only the references from this supplier should populate the dataGridComboBox column.

I thought I know how to do it, but obviously something is missing. I don't have any error but my dataGridComboBox column is still empty.

## **View**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="supplierComboBox"
                      Margin="5" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource supplier}}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="supplier"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Supplier,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="idfoodSupplier"
                      Text="{Binding SupplierText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Width="160"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInvoice" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ref Supplier"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Reference, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="refsup" 
                                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding refSup}" 
                                            SelectedValuePath="refsup"
                                            Width="*"/>  
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

## **ViewModel**

```
public class InvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {


        public Context ctx = new Context();

        Invoice invoice;

        public InvoiceViewModel()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<PreInvoice>();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<PreInvoice> collection;

        public ObservableCollection<PreInvoice> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return collection;
            }
            set
            {
                collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
            }
        }

        private foodSupplier _supplier;
        public foodSupplier Supplier
        {
            get
            {
                return _supplier;
            }
            set
            {
                _supplier = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Supplier");
                Reference = new List<product>();
                Reference = (from p in ctx.products
                              where p.supplier == _supplier.idfoodSupplier
                              select p).ToList();
            }
        }

        private List<product> _reference;

        public List<product> Reference
        {
            get
            {
                return _reference;
            }
            set
            {
                _reference = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Reference");
            }
        }


        public class PreInvoice : ViewModelBase
        {
            public string refSup {get; set;}


        }
    }
```

## **Product Model**

```
public partial class product
{
    public int idproduct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> supplier { get; set; }
    public string refsup { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual foodSupplier foodSupplier { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DataGridComboBoxColumn` or any other supported data grid columns are not part of visual tree of datagrid so they don't inherit the DataContext of datagrid. Since, they don't lie in visual tree so any try to get `DataContext` using RelativeSource won't work.

Solution - You can create a proxy element to bind the data context of window; use that proxy element to bind the `ItemsSource` of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. For ex :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Vm, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ComboBox x:Name="supplierComboBox"
                      Margin="5" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource supplier}}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="supplier"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Supplier,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="idfoodSupplier"
                      Text="{Binding SupplierText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Width="160"/>

        <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"></ContentControl>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInvoice" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ref Supplier"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Reference, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="refsup" 
                                            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding refSup}" 
                                            SelectedValuePath="refsup"
                                            Width="*"/>  
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The ProxyElement is any FrameworkElement that steals the DataContext from the main View and offers it to the logical child such as DataGridColumn. For that it must be hosted as a Content into an invisible ContentControl which is under the same View.

Comment: and how do I do if I need to order the items in the dataGridCombobox column?